# @TestPropertySource(locations={"classpath: application -test.properties"}) is not reading the properties file values

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I am using junit to write the test cases, but am not able to read the property file values

Am using below annotation on top of the test class
@TestPropertySource(locations={"classpath: application -test.properties"})
But no use

Comment: There is far too little information here to be able to answer this.